# validation on invoice

Tags: invoice, validation

I want to add a validation when the we click on the button 'invoice'.

In the code `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Invoice/View.php`,
we have the function

```
public function getInvoiceUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_invoice/start');
    }
```

where can I see the code of `*/sales_order_invoice/start` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

File you are looking for is located in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php`. Look for `startAction()` method, this will be your starting point.

I don't know what exactly are you trying to do but this is probably not the best place to implement your code. Besides, you should not modify core files directly. Maybe we can give you better advice if you provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Magento tells you where the Url is located simply by the way it is structured.  You can start by looking at the getUrl().  It is `*/sales_order_invoice/start`.

Magento's URLs are broken down like this: `/frontName/controllerName/actionMethod/`

Since you're in the admin, the frontName `*` will really be `adminhtml`

This means that your getUrl() address is:

`adminhtml/sales_order_invoice/start`

Based on this, you know you need to start by changing to `app/code/core/Mage`

***Remember: Don't edit the core. Take the time to learn how to override the controller to make your modifications. It's worth it.***

Next, you'll see that the frontName is `adminhtml`.  So change to the "Adminhtml" folder.

You're wanting to access the controller, so navigate to the `controllers` folder next.

The controllerName is `sales_order_invoice`. Remember that Magento treats underscores as slashes `_ = /` which makes the `sales_order_invoice` location `Sales/Order/` and the last part is the controller file name. This means you'll see a file in the folder called `InvoiceController.php`.

The final location of the file containing your action is:

`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php`

The last piece of the url is `start`. In the controller file, this part is always followed by "Action".  So, `start` means you'll find a function in the InvoiceController.php file called `startAction()`.

Learn about the Magento Controller Dispatch and you'll never have to ask where a function is located.  You'll know by the url itself.